# Google maps api geocoder - restrict to multiple countries

Tags: api, maps, geocoder

Im using google geocoder and I want to restrict result to some countries (for example I don't want to search in USA).

Using:

```
componentRestrictions: {
                  country: 'de'
}
```

Works fine, but I would like to add more countries, tried passing array:

```
componentRestrictions: {
                  country: ['de','at','ch']
              }
```

But it gives an error

Is there anyway to add more than one country to restrictions?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide error traceback.

Comment: I'm currently looking for an answer to this too. For now, it appears that the Geocoding API doesn't accept an array of countries like the places.Autocomplete does. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-multiple-countries

Comment: Sorry to revive an old question, but if anyone stumbles across this, using the python library, I needed to add `components=country:DE` to the request url.
Did it like this: `googlemaps.Client(key='my_key', requests_kwargs={'params': {'components': ['country:DE']}}`
Hope this helps someone!